# Cannot Install Virtual Machine Manager 2008 R2 because Installation cannot start Server service

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v

I am attempting to install VMM 2008 R2 on my Windows 2008 R2 box. I had it going and after some issues had to uninstall and am now attempting to reinstall. Now I get the error:

> Configuration of Virtual Machine Manager failed. For more information about configuration, see "Troubleshooting" in the Virtual Machine Manager Setup help.
>   ID: 292. Details: The Server service is not started

From what I can tell it is not even installing the service. Does anyone have any ideas what could be going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Server service is a core component of Windows and is not something that is installed with any other product, Microsoft or otherwise. If the Server service is missing it could be that you've uninstalled the File and Printer sharing component, which will uninstall the Server service so maybe that's what's going on.

Comment: Glad to help...